# Maven/Jacoco - add Cucumber test results to the Jacoco code coverage overview

Tags: maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

Question: how can I show the code coverage results of Cucumber (functional tests) in the Jacoco overview?

Q2: Can I merge that with e.g. Unit and/or Integration test results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging unit-, integration and functional tests should not be merged. They have different goals.

**BUT - Cucumber tests can also be used to perform (IT) unit and/or integration testing.**

If you would like to merge unittests, then you could look at the following simple demo project. The same applies for Integration tests. Functional tests.

- Multi module project
- Unit test (via mvn clean install)
- Integration test (via mvn clean install -P integration-test)
- **Cucumber tests** (via mvn clean install) - to demo unit/it-testing
- Jacoco - test coverage ( both aggregate datafile and aggregate reporting)
- FindBugs - code quality

Enjoy the [sipmle demo project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-unittest-integrationtest-jacoco.git).